# VirtualBox: Bridge VM to pseudo adapter

Tags: linux, networking, virtualbox, virtual-machine, bridged

I have 4 VMs running on my host, using them as containers for stuff like my web applications. However, I currently am using NGINX as a reverse proxy - and the problems that come with that. So I decided that I wanted to map my VM to an external IP.

My provider linked my server to 5 IPs, that I configured on my host as `eth0`, `eth0:0`, `eth0:1`, `eth0:2` and `eth0:3`. The `:N` suffix comes from my provider's (OVH) tutorial on how to set them up.

When I now go to Virtual Box through phpVirtualBox, I can attach a new network device. But when I select "Bridged", I only see my `eth0`, and zero of it's pseudos.

How can I tell VirtualBox to just map the VM to my IP? My goal is to make the VM completely aware of the external IP and have it behave like the IP belonged to it entirely - ergo, all open ports on the VM are open on that IP, etc.

Comment: You should not be configuring your additional IPs on your host.  You should be using the bridged networking adapter in VirtualBox, and then configuring your IP inside the VM.

Comment: @heavyd I just tried that out - removed the IP from the host, set bridged to eth0 and configured the IP inside the guest - unfortunately, to no avail. It appearently can not reach outside itself. When I try to ping `8.8.8.8` I get a "Host unreachable".

Comment: Can you still ping from the host?  When the IP was assigned to the host were you able to ping using that IP?

Comment: @heavyd I did look through the VBox forums, and found out why things just didnt work out. I needed to have the provider's permission - because bridge mode also requires a MAC addr. So I got a virtual-mac for my VM, inserted that, and boosh. It works now :) Going to close the question now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue got resolved:

First of, I removed the alias entries that I wanted to put to my VM(s) from the host.

Then, I needed to set up my guest's IP according to my provider's instructions. That involved assigning the IP statically to the adapter and alike.

Then, bridge the VM with `eth0`. That is fine, because that interface also gets accessed through the IP.

With this done, I can now properly connect to the VM, just like it should be.

Resources:

- http://hilfe.ovh.de/BridgeClient
- https://forums.virtualbox.org/viewtopic.php?f=7&t=58489

Tipp:

I used the VRDP protocol to connect to my VM and set it up. Make sure that the virtual MAC address - or the address that your provider allows you to use - is inserted *whilst the VM is offline*. You have to do this from your host to ensure that it works as expected. Further, it might confuse you how my provider suggested `route add`/`route del` for the pre/post scripts. It turns out that this is actually neccessary - and I have no idea why. But it worked that way.